# JQuery - Append to text area that has been modified with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I am trying to append the value of a div or a input box to my text area. I have this working no problem but if i clear the contents of the text area first with a Jquery action it doesnt allow me to use my append features.

E.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#Column1").click(function () {
        $("#sql").append($("#Column1").val())
   })

    $("#Column2").click(function () {
        $("#sql").append($("#Column2").html())
   })

  $("#reset_sql").click(function () {
        $("#sql").val('SELECT ')
   })
</script>


<div> <input type="checkbox" name="column1" id="column1" value="`Column1`"> column1 </div>
<div id="Column2"> Column2 </div>

<textarea rows="10" cols="80" name="sql" id="sql"><? echo $sql ;?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
<input type="button" value="reset sql" id="reset_sql" />
```

The input and div lines above are just generic examples but relate exactly to what i'm trying to do.

I dont understand that when i clear the text area with javascript that my appends wont work. I get no JS errors in firefox error console.

thank you

Comment: You haven't closed off your document ready function.  You're missing `});` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox has an id of 'column1', but your event handler is `$("#Column1").click(function () {`.

Case matters! Either change the id to 'Column1' or the event handler to look for `$('#column1')`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n95vn/)

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues with your code: you haven't closed your document.ready callback, you are using the incorrect case when refering to your ID's, and you're using some of the jQuery methods incorrectly. For example, `append()` appends HTML to an element, whereas you want to update the value.

Your logic isn't quite correct either, since columns won't be removed when you uncheck a checkbox, and the columns won't be comma delimited (it looks like you are building a SQL string here).

I believe something like this is what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $sql = $('#sql');
    var initialValue = $sql.val();

   $("#column1, #column2").on('change', function () {
       var cols = [];

       var checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').each(function() {
           cols.push($(this).val());
       });

       $sql.val(initialValue + ' ' + cols.join(', '));
   })

   $("#reset_sql").on('click', function () {
        $sql.val(initialValue)
   })
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KQmpK/3)**